# задать определенные биты битовыми операциями

Tags: c#, битовые-операции

Добрый день. Вот есть массив сырых байт `byte[] arr = new byte[3];` и нужно заполнить биты, допустим, следующим образом:

```
01101 001

0000 0001

0000 0001
```

Биты возрастают справа налево. Интересует следующее: как используя только битовые операции задать число 01101 лишь старшим пяти битам из первого байта массива? Иными словами, помогите пожалуйста реализовать функцию `void set_five_bits(byte a, byte[] dump)`, где `a` - число которое нужно задать старшим пяти битам первого элемента массива `dump`. `BitArray` использовать нельзя.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для реализации таких операций используются законы *булевой алгебры*, в частности:

```
x & 1 = x
x & 0 = 0
x | 1 = 1
x | 0 = x
```

Соответственно, чтобы установить старшие биты в 01101, не трогая младшие биты, вы сначала сбрасываете нужные биты в 0:

```
x & 0b01101111
```

А затем устанавливаете нужные биты в 1:

```
(x & 0b01101111) | 0b01101000
```

Но это можно делать и в противоположном порядке.
Трюком здесь являются значения младших бит — для каждой операции они выбраны так, чтобы не изменить исходные биты числа. В старшей части мы тоже трогаем только те биты, которые можем изменить с помощью операции.

Префикс `0b` для двоичных чисел хотели ввести в C# 6, теперь перенесли на C# 7, так что использовать придётся шестнадцеричную запись:

```
(x & 0x6F) | 0x68
```

Теперь о том, как сделать эту операцию для любого набора из 5 бит. Здесь нам пригодится операция битового сдвига:

```
0b01101 << 3 == 0b01101000
```

В данном случае мы сдвинули битовый шаблон на 3 бита влево, чтобы он изменял только старшие 5 бит. Так мы получили константу для установки битов.

Чтобы получить константу для сброса битов, мы должны установить младшие 3 бита в 1, тогда при выполнении операции `&` они не изменят младшие три бита числа:

```
(0b01101 << 3) | 0b00000111 == 0b01101111
```

Соответственно:

```
byte set_five_bits(byte a, byte x)
{
    byte or_pattern = a << 3;
    byte and_pattern = or_pattern | 0x07;

    return x & and_pattern | or_pattern;
}
```

Comment: and_pattern проще взять строго равным 7

Comment: И в последней строке у вас что-то странное написано...

Comment: воо, за разъяснения огромное спасибо

Comment: @PavelMayorov Спасибо, исправил. Рука дрогнула, когда набирал ответ. Что касается `and_pattern` — мне кажется так, как сейчас написано, проще понять, поэтому написал так.